# Error: "Test class not found in selected project"

Tags: android, android-testing, junit3

I am testing a simple application. When i start JUnit testing, although i get test run finished, I am not getting any result. Pop up menu showing "Test Class not found". Could anyone fix this?

**Stack trace :**

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class com.example.testbuild.test.second has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)

```
package com.example.testbuild.test;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.testbuild.MainActivity;

public class second extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    MainActivity a;
    Button b;
    TextView v;
    public second(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
      @Override
      protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        a=getActivity();
        b=(Button)a.findViewById(com.example.testbuild.R.id.button1);
        v=(TextView)a.findViewById(com.example.testbuild.R.id.textView1);
          }
      public void clicking()
      {

          a.runOnUiThread(
                  new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        b.performClick();
                    }
                  });
          String s=v.getText().toString();
             Assert.assertEquals("test passed", "Hello",s);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the constructor will not pass any arguments. try:

```
public second(){
   super(MainActivity.class);
}
```